# Handling an array received from mysql stored procedure in laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array from my mysql database using a stored procedure.

```php
$data = DB::connection('mysql')->select("CALL sp_GetLink('y')");
```

If I do this

```php
var_dump($data);
```

This is the output :

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#216 (1) {
        ["ORIGINAL"]=> string(22) "tttttttttttttttttttttt"
    }
}
```

If I do this

```php
return $data;
```

This is the output :

```
[{"ORIGINAL":"tttttttttttttttttttttt"}]
```

This is what I want it to output :
tttttttttttttttttttttt

The things that I have tried but unsuccessful:

```php
return $data->value["ORIGINAL"];
return (string)$data;
return $data->ORIGINAL;
return $data->row['ORIGINAL'];
return $data->ORIGINAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your output, you are getting an array result from your query response. Can you try `return $data[0]["ORIGINAL"];` or  `return $data[0]->ORIGINAL`; ?